# How to invoke a boolean variable from another method?

Tags: variables, methods, boolean

I have a boolean variable defined in "methodA" and i want to use it in another method "methodB" of the same class but i do get always an error.I cannot make it public static like the other variables.Any ideas how to do this correctly?

Comment: Why not just declare it at class level??

Comment: how to do this? when write publis static boolean myValue ; this does not work!! how to do your recommandation?

Comment: May be if you could show us some code we would be able to help you....!

Comment: boolean myValue= true ;  is what i have, and i want this to be reached anywhere in its class!!!

Comment: Can you post your class declaration ?

Comment: thx guys, i have solve the problem by declaring the variable at class level as Shashank said!